# Someone please explain the Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null) algorithm

Tags: javascript

suppose we have this code

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null));
}
```

where arr is an array of arrays.

1. first,why must i use apply()?

I understand that when using the method Math.max() to operate on an array i must add the apply() method also. So i'll have something like this `Math.max.apply(null, arr)` why? what does apply() do?

2. In this code `arr.map(Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null))` what does bind() really do?

Please give an explanation i can understand,i really appreciate this.

Comment: bind recreate the function with own properties, if you already used the event can be recreate ... etc ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the entire expression:

```
arr.map(Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null));
```

*map* expects its first argument to be a function, which is returned by:

```
Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null);
```

*Function.apply* is a shorter version of *Function.prototype.apply*.

Calling *bind* on it returns a special version of *apply* whose *this* is set to *Math.max* and when called, will have as it's first parameter (i.e. the value that would normally be used as *this*) set to *null*, since it's not going to be used.

So each element in *arr* will effectively be called using:

```
Math.max.apply(null, member);
```

The use of *apply* means the values in member are passed as parameters, as if:

```
Math.max(member[0],member[1] ... member[n]);
```

So the expression returns the maximum value in each array. Those values are returned to *map*, which puts them into a new array.

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
console.log(
  arr.map(Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null)) //[3, 6]
);
```

and is effectively the same as:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]];
console.log(
  arr.map(function(a) {return Math.max.apply(null, a)}) //[3, 6]
);
```

Though using recent features you might use destructing with rest parameter syntax:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]];
console.log(
  arr.map(a => Math.max(...a))   // [3, 6]
);
```

Comment: i really appreciate your answer.Thank you. Why must apply() take null as argument,then member.why not only member?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, `.apply` calls a function with the set of arguments(array-like) passed to it.

EG:

```
const add = (...args) => args.reduce((acc, next) => acc + next);
```

I can call the `add` function with any number of arguments using the `.apply` method like this.

```
add.apply(null, [4, 2, 6, 76, 9]) // => 97.
```

You call also use `.call` but instead of passing in array-like arguments, you simply pass in the values

```
add.call(null, 4, 2, 6, 76, 9) // => 97.
```

With `.bind`, the difference is that it creates a new function with call be called later.

```
const addFunc = add.bind(null, 4, 2, 6, 76, 9);
addFunc() // -> 97.
```

So, as it applies to the function we defined, it also applies to inbuild functions like `Math.max`, `Math.min`, etc.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The `Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null)` creates a function definition when invoked takes `null` as the first parameter by default and any provided parameters will come second. So as a callback to `arr.map` this function (due to `bind` statement) will be bound to `Math.max` however the `Function.apply`'s first parameter will be `null` and second is going the be the sub array item of the main array (of which the items are to be passed as arguments to `Math.max` function).

This is an old trick and in ES6 terms `arr.map(s => Math.max(...s));` would do the same job much more clearly.